# Multiple responses with one Ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a button that opens a bootstrap modal and loads some data from a json file into the `modal-body` with an ajax GET request. I've added a second button (OK) to the modal to increment a number (inside the object from the json file) and post the object as a string to a php file (to update the json file and print the number) by an ajax POST request.
The problem is when I click OK for the second time, I got 2 responses. And when I click OK for the third time, I got 3 responses, and so on the responses are incremented.
It's like there is some counter that counts how many time the modal was opened.
Even when I don't click OK and just close the modal this counter is incremented and when I click OK the responses fire up and their number is equal to the times I opened the modal.
I thought the ajax request is responsible, but I deleted it and still got multiple responses as I can see from the console.
So I think it is something wrong with the modal and the button I added to it, but I don't know what.

**Here is the html for the modal:**

```
<!-- Modal 1 -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="Modal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal contents-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="mBody1"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ok1" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div
```

**And this is jQuery:**

```
$('.dr1').click(function(){
    $('#Modal1').modal();
    $('.modal-header, .modal-footer').css("border-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/resources/doctors.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(doctors) {
            $('#mBody1').html('You are requisting a reservation for<br/>Dr. ' +doctors[0].name+ '<br/>Your number is ' +(doctors[0].nNo+1));
            $('.ok1').click(function() {
                doctors[0].nNo=doctors[0].nNo+1;
                console.log(doctors);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/resources/newTic.php',
                    data: {data: JSON.stringify(doctors), drNo: "1" },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(msg) {
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that's because with each `.success` you are adding yet another `$('.ok1').click(function() {` - you should investigate jQuery documentation to see how you can remove the click event before adding it

Comment: Yes, thank you @JaromandaX
I added `$('.ok1').off("click");` to the end of `.click` event and it worked!

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work at the end of `success` function, and I place it inside the `$('.ok1').click()` event function it generate multiple responses if I close the modal and reopen it. So I have to place it at the end of `$('.dr1').click()` event function.

Comment: Still buggy! it doesn't increment the number some times, especially when I just toggle the modal without clicking OK. And if I do that (toggle modal) for some time, I get multiple responses again. :(